# Importance of maximum, minimum, and preferred dimensions in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, javafx-8, dimension

I don't understand the use of maximum, minimum, and preferred heights and widths of classes in the JavaFX library.

For example, the PopUpControl class in JavaFX 8 has the methods, `setMaxHeight()`, `setMinHeight`, and `setPrefHeight()`. I don't know what significance each one has.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you resize your window?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure what you're saying, but I would like everything to remain at the same relative size, compared to each other.

Comment: I was answering you. That is what those settings control. Which components should collapse, resize, force drag bars, etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I appreciate the help, but I am waiting for an answer that is more in-depth, if possible.

Comment: Min means the node bounds will not go below that value. Max means the node bounds will not go above that value. Preferred means the bounds the node will be unless a parent or someone other constraint says different.

Comment: The best way to learn more is to create visual layouts using SceneBuilder. Use different Parent nodes and different settings.